# Render and download data table in Rshiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am unable to render a data table and allow users to download that data table with a shiny application. Here is my MWE

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Tool v0.03"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  fileInput("dataset", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv")),
  helpText(em("Note:Select all the inputs and click on button as given below to exectute the app")),
  checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
  radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
               choices = c(Comma = ",",
                           Semicolon = ";",
                           Tab = "\t"),
               selected = ","),
  selectInput("select", "Select columns to display", c('col1', 'col2'), multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton("update", "Update Data set", class = "btn-primary",style='padding:4px; font-size:120%')
),
mainPanel(

  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel(h2("Random Stratified Sample"), DT::dataTableOutput('out.Sample'), 
                       fluidRow(downloadButton('SampleDownload', "Download sample data"))) # in a tabitem)
)
)
)
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(session, input, output) {

data <- reactive({
req(input$dataset)
Cleaning_Fun(read.csv(input$dataset$datapath, header = input$header,sep = 
input$sep))
})

filtereddata <- eventReactive({
input$update
data()
},  {
req(data())
if(is.null(input$select) || input$select == "")
  data() else 
    data()[, colnames(data()) %in% input$select]
})

observeEvent(data(), {
updateSelectInput(session, "select", choices=colnames(data()))
})

output$out.Sample <- 
DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable((filtereddata())

))

output$SampleDownload <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste('Sample_data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')
},
content = function(file){
  write.csv(filtereddata()[input[["SampleData_rows_all"]], ],file)
}
)

}
```

This example allows the user to render and download a dataset that they have uploaded. Unfortunately the file only contains the header of the data table. Unsure where this is going wrong but, any help appreciated

Thanks,
John

Comment: Where is `input$SampleData_rows_all` in your `ui`? You're only writing rows of `filtereddata()` whose rownames match the values of `input$SampleData_rows_all`. If `input$SampleData_rows_all` is not defined anywhere, you're going to be selecting 0 rows and just getting the column headers.

Comment: Do not use a dot in the input/output names, like `output$out.Sample`. The dot has a meaning in Javascript and shiny will interpret this as Javascript.

Comment: @divibisan I guess this is a confusion from the OP. If he/she replaces `output$out.Sample` with `output$SampleData`, then `input$SampleData_rows_all` will be automatically defined by `DT`.

Comment: You do not need a `downloadHandler` with `DT`. Use the `Buttons` extension instead (this is cleaner and offers more options): `DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(filtereddata(), extensions="Buttons", options=list(dom="Bfrtip", buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print")))`.